# Sql server 2005 :How to Import objects of a schema to another

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have created several objects (Tables,Stored Procs, functions etc.) under a new schema (x)

Now I want to import them to DBO schema.

How can I do that..
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to transfer them from your other schema so they now belong to the dbo schema? If so this is the syntax you need.

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER OtherSchema.ObjectName;
```